# problems of display modis ndvi with TIMESAT

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modis, envi

I use MODIS MRT tool mosicia tow tiles MODIS NDVI data, then use TIMESAT image view to display the mosaic data, encounting file size waring :
[image]

and after drawing data, the sequences of two tiles is wrong, original data display sequence is right to left, but display result is left to right.
[image]

but when i use ARCGIS or envi to display the mosaic data, the display sequence is ok.
[image]

so i want to know what is wrong with my mosaic data?

Answer (score 2):

At present, this problem has been solved. I use MRT tool mosaic 2 tiles data, and then output GEOTIFF format,finally using ENVI software open the GEOTIFF file and save it as ENVI Stand. then i open it with TImesat image view, the presentation sequence is right.

Comment: Hi GUTGIS. I have a same problem to open time series images in ENVI stand format on TIMESAT. The problem is exact the same with the problem you encountered above. My image size is so big col is 12618, row is 4144. I'm wondered that Timesat can open such big images? What was the image size you used in TIMESAT?

Answer (score 0):

You use gdal_translate to convert the format of file to IDRISI (RST). and the data type to byte or 16int. For example:

```
gdal_translate -ot Byte -a_nodata -9999 -scale -0.200000 0.500000 1.000000 255.000000 -of RST input.img output.rst
```

Comment: You might want to expand your answer a bit to explain how a file format conversion addresses the issues described in the question (size error, reversal of image).

Answer (score 0):

I used MOD13Q1 NDVI data and then I converted it to **generic binary format** also the projection to WGS84 using **HEG Tool** , open timesat then input rows and columns, int type (available in .hdr file, use notepad++ to view).

At first you can also try converting your data into Geotiff format using **HEG Tool** and carry out the mosaic and subset process in ArcMap and then save it to .dat(ENVI std. format)

In case if file is not reading in timesat then open .dat file in ENVI and save it as Envi Std. format (choose BSQ, integer). Open it in timesat.

Hope this process also help others!